# HttpClient created without HttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java-8, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

It is clear that connectionManager has limits on number of connections per route, etc. But I can create HttpClient also without mentioning connectionManagers, in that scenario, which are the limits of the httpClient? Is some connectionManager used by default?

Answer (score 1):

2 per distinct route, 20 in total

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! Do you also know if PoolingHttpClientConnetionManager has some limits? I can set defaultMaxPerRoute e maxTotal at 200, does it mean that now the JVM will handle 200 different connections or is there still some max number of simultaneous connection handled by tomcat for instance?